# How to increase the font size of index in grouped listview,Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Grouped listview in Xamarin Forms Xaml page. The list is grouped alphabetically. How to increase the Font size of the index (A,B,C,D....)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupHeaderTemplate to customise the group header.

```
<ListView IsGroupingEnabled="True">    
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```